PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 22): Away in a Manger
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
The stars in the bright sky looked down where he lay.

Hint:

 

Hint:

 The lighting can be a little deceiving, but the stuff under the fire is the same color as the male sheep.


Complete answer (I think)
The message is

 MERRY CHRISTMAS

The completed crossword grids

 Are 3x3 word squares derived from 3 letter words based on the objects with corresponding colours.
 
 (Ohm is in reverse because of its shadow in the picture making it upside-down) (Also those with maybe not so keen eyes look at Mary’s right arm).


 Then we use the ‘pigpen symbols’ to extract the letters based on the colour and the positioning of the letter on the grids and then read the message left to right up, down.


Nice solve :) Didn't get anywhere as close myself. At what point did you notice the w--- s----- element to it? +1

@Stiv Ha! I thought you were going to snipe me as I was getting close to solving it! I had suspicions based on the hints and a previous puzzle by the op from a while back. Then the ash and ram were the first things I saw which began to support the theory. But the real break through was when I tried it for white and I was able to complete it.
